# Camera preview remains black after restarting the cameraview from Marshmallow (Android 6.0)

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I am using google's library [cameraview](https://github.com/google/cameraview) to integrate the camera API for different version.

**This issue is coming on API 25 only.**

When I restart the camera after capturing image. It remains black on the screen. I could not find any solution regarding NOUGAT api lib. How can I solve the camera preview generation again. please let me know if there is any solution for the particular naugat version. First image is when I start my activity. It will capture the image but after capturing my image I restart the camera view it will remains black. **Other lower then Android 6.0 it is working fine.**

[image]
[image: This how I see the screen after restarting the camera]

Comment: Finally got the solution.

Comment: can you post the solution ?

Comment: well?  Solution please